# Sscanf not properly matching single quotes

Tags: string, go, formatting

I working on some Go code but I am having troubles figuring out why my string isn't being scanned correctly.

I'm given a string that looks like this:

```
"ERROR: 1: something happened 'here'"
```

I'm trying to scan it like this:

```
n, err := fmt.Sscanf("ERROR: 1: something happened 'here'", "ERROR: 1: something happened '%50s'", &value)
```

However, every time I check the result of the value, I get something like this:

```
here'
```

Where the last single quote is left in.

Any idea how to fix this? I figured this case wouldn't be non-deterministic because the function can't complete formatting without including the quote.

Of course, I can simply remove the last character, but I would prefer a `fmt`-based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builtin [fmt.Scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scanner) has no way to do what you're trying to do. If the target text was wrapped in double quotes, you could use the `%q` specifier.

Alternatively, if the target was a single wrapped character, you could use `text/scanner`. But because your target is neither of those, there's nothing built in. So, your options are `regexp`, or `bufio` with a custom scanner, or even just `strings.Split`. If you insist on using `fmt` you can do a custom scanner, but it's probably the worst option of everything:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type quote struct { tok string }

func (q *quote) Scan(state fmt.ScanState, verb rune) error {
   tok, err := state.Token(false, func(r rune) bool {
      return r != 0x27 // '
   })
   if err != nil {
      return err
   }
   if _, _, err := state.ReadRune(); err != nil {
      if len(tok) == 0 {
         panic(err)
      }
   }
   q.tok = string(tok)
   return nil
}
```

Example:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   r := strings.NewReader("ERROR: 1: something happened 'here'")
   for {
      var q quote
      _, err := fmt.Fscan(r, &q)
      if err != nil {
         break
      }
      fmt.Printf("%q\n", q.tok)
   }
}
```

Result:

```
"ERROR: 1: something happened "
"here"
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, just seems weird it can't be handled naturally. I guess I was making the incorrect assumption that Sscanf used `regexp`.

Comment: @StevenPenny something wrong is going on ?

Comment: @mh-cbon everything is fine, thank you for the concern